# Json string not able to display using jquery

Tags: jquery, json

My web service is returning a JSON array called jsonString. I am using jQuery mobile. This has the value:

```
{
    "id": "10844",
    "password": "acddcd",
    "role": ["PortalAdmin,ViewAllJob,SetupAdmin,Budget Approval,MarketingAdmin,ProjectManagementAdmin,HRAdmin,PayRollAdmin,SCMAdmin,VendorPortalAdmin,FinanceAdmin,AnalyticsAdmin"],
    "userName": "portaluser"
}
```

What displaying this array in a text box (where `#as` is the text box):

```
$('#as').val(jsonString);
```

When I use this code :

```
var a = {
    "id": "10844",
    "password": "acddcd",
    "role": ["PortalAdmin,ViewAllJob,SetupAdmin,Budget Approval,MarketingAdmin,ProjectManagementAdmin,HRAdmin,PayRollAdmin,SCMAdmin,VendorPortalAdmin,FinanceAdmin,AnalyticsAdmin"],
    "userName": "portaluser"
};
alert(a.id);
```

I get the right answer i.e. `10844` However, when I use this code:

```
var a=jsonString;
alert(a.id);
```

I get `undefined`. Why?

Comment: If you using jQuery `ajax` then you can add `dataType: "JSON"` parameter to request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you create an object, when you acces this object's `id` property, there is no problem.

In the second case you give your variable a JSON as a string. That doesn't have an `id` attribute, you have to parse the JSON string first, than you can acces its attributes.

Do this in the second case:

```
var a = JSON.parse(jsonString);
alert(a.id);
```

If `jsonString` is not a string but an object there is two thing to mention:

1. As [rockStar said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21847738) be sure that your variable exists and you assigned the result from your web service to your `jsonString` variable.
2. This is bad naming. If you call it `jsonString` others suppose that it is a string. If it is an object then call it `jsonObject` or `jsonResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var JSONstring = {
    "id": "10844",
    "password": "acddcd",
    "role": ["PortalAdmin,ViewAllJob,SetupAdmin,Budget Approval,MarketingAdmin,ProjectManagementAdmin,HRAdmin,PayRollAdmin,SCMAdmin,VendorPortalAdmin,FinanceAdmin,AnalyticsAdmin"],
    "userName": "portaluser"
};
```

you need to define ur `JSONstring` and the rest of your code is working,

```
var a = JSONstring;
alert(a.id);
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Tthf/)

Comment: as he didn't initialized it from his question code block, so he might just missed this as it will become undefined, as it is not defined.